# Convert the ASCII text given in a text box, to hexadecimal format in another string

Tags: c#, string, hex, ascii

I've been trying to figure this out for hours to no avail, looked at other questions like this yet I can't seem to figure out how to use their solution in my code. For clarification, I'm looking for a way for me to convert the string UsernamePreHex, to hexadecimal in the string UsernamePostHex, to be used in memory writing below.

```
public string UsernamePreHex;
public string UsernamePostHex;

private void darkTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UsernamePreHex = darkTextBox1.Text;
    
}

private void darkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (darkTextBox1.Text == "")
    {
        DarkMessageBox.ShowInformation("Please click the 'Invisible Name' button, or enter a name in the text box first", "Error");
    }
    else
    m.WriteMemory("base+15840A28,40C", "bytes", UsernamePostHex+" 00");
    DarkMessageBox.ShowInformation("Name has been set to "+UsernamePostHex, "Success!");
}
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far. Anyway, the approach should be string->bytes->hex string.

Comment: Shouldn't there be brackets around the else? This way 'ShowInformation' is called always.

Answer (score -1):

```
public string GetHexValue(string inputString)
{
    byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(inputString);
    string hexString = System.BitConverter.ToString(byteArray);
    return hexString;
}
```

Comment: [Encoding.Default docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.default?view=net-5.0#remarks): _"Different computers can use different encodings as the default, and the default encoding can change on a single computer. If you use the Default encoding to encode and decode data streamed between computers or retrieved at different times on the same computer, it may translate that data incorrectly"_